# WordPress Adding Variables to Loop Arguments

Tags: wordpress, loops, variables

I have a custom post-type call Called 'Sectors' and another post type called 'Challenges' The challenges post type has a taxonomy called 'sectortype' - which has the same names as the sectors.

I created a page called 'single-sector.php' On that page displays a loop that includes challenges related to that sector.

When I write the loop for displaying challenges, how do I make the 'sectortype' => 'advanced-education' a variable so it will work on other single sector pages?

Here's what I have for the loop...

```
<?php $challenge_args = array(
     'post_type' => 'challenge',
     'sectortype' => 'advanced-education', //Need Help Here
      );
// create a new instance of WP_Query
$challenge_query = new WP_Query( $challenge_args );
?>
<?php if ( $challenge_query->have_posts() ) : while ($challenge_query->have_posts() ) : $challenge_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get Custom posts by custom taxonomy terms :

```
<?php
   $terms = get_terms('sectortype');
   $challenge_args = array(
   'post_type' => 'challenge',
   'publish_status' => 'published',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sectortype',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $terms[0], //whichever term you want to select
      ),
    ),
);
// create a new instance of WP_Query
$challenge_query = new WP_Query( $challenge_args );
?>
<?php if ( $challenge_query->have_posts() ) : while ($challenge_query->have_posts() ) : $challenge_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
```

**DISPLAY IN SEPARATE PAGES**
TO display the posts in separate pages as you mentioned in the comment, you have to do the following:

Create Separate Page Links:: (use on page as navigation items)

```
<?php $categories = get_terms('sectortype');?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $categories as $key => $c ):?>
      <?php $cat_link = get_term_link( $c->term_id );?>
      <?php $term_title= single_term_title('', false);?>
      <li class="<?php echo ($c->name == $term_title )?'active':'';?>"><a href="<?php echo $cat_link;?>"><?php echo $c->name;?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach;?>
 </ul>
```

Create a file in theme directory (actually an archive template for taxonomy terms) with the filename 'taxonomy-sectortype.php'.

On that template, get the posts from the usual loop without using any queries and you will get the respective posts.

Comment: For the taxonomy, I have categories such as business, advanced-education etc. So with the edits you provided (thank you) that should display posts from a given taxonomy on the correct page without having to create a new page for each one?